# Multiple items from .select() linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have used a lot of SQL in the past but am new to LINQ. I have the following query which selects the `otherID` from the relevant table successfully, however when I try to select multiple columns I am unable to do so. 
This is my following query:

```
var getQ = db.Requests.Where(x => temp.Contains(x.carID)).Select(x => x.otherID).ToList();
```

I have tried

```
var getQ = db.Requests.Where(x => temp.Contains(x.carID)).Select(x => x.otherID && x.dayID).ToList();
```

I am unable to get it to work, any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use a[nonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) to return multiple columns

```
var getQ = db.Requests.Where(x => temp.Contains(x.carID))
                      .Select(x => new { OtherID = x.otherID, DayID = x.dayID).ToList();
```

You can make a custom class, as the anonymous type could not be returned from method.

```
class YourClass
{
    public int OtherID { get; set; }
    public int DayID { get; set; }
}

var getQ = db.Requests.Where(x => temp.Contains(x.carID))
                      .Select(x => new YourClass { OtherID = x.otherID, DayID = x.dayID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

make the change is the select statement:

```
    var getQ = db.Requests.Where(x => temp.Contains(x.carID)).Select(x => new{x.otherID, x.dayID}).ToList();
```

Comment: select always return collection of object, so you have to create object in select statement.